# На nginx не работает блокировка по IP

Tags: nginx, сервер, ip

на сайте [leadertask.ru](https://www.leadertask.ru) в конфиг /etc/nginx/nginx.conf подключили файл со списком ip для блокировки

> include blockips.conf;
> deny 195.239.143.114;
> deny 178.20.235.164; 
> deny 83.242.179.139;
> deny 95.217.59.106;
> deny 77.73.129.20; 
> deny 45.154.98.221; 
> deny 65.108.44.54; 
> deny 65.109.51.246; 
> deny 13.93.6.174; 
> deny 64.124.8.72; 
> deny 185.196.220.26; 
> deny 62.141.38.215; 
> deny 183.88.47.19; 
> deny 139.99.3.196; 
> deny 109.161.45.166;

в последнем добавил свой IP для проверки работы конфига. К сожалению не работает.

Подскажите в какую сторону посмотреть чтобы решить проблему?

сам конфиг:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##
        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 301;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;
        index              index.php index.html index.htm;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        ## Block spammers and other unwanted visitors  ##   
        include blockips.conf;

"nginx.conf" 98L, 1836B                                                                               21,25-32      Top
```

Comment: a) это явно не весь конфиг. б) нужен ещё конфиг серверного блока.